# Compilation error : "no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Card*>::insert(int, Card*&)’" C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vector, compilation

I try to use insert function of vector but I get a compilation error saying:

src/Hand.cpp:71:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::insert(int, Card&)’
         Vvalues[place]->getVcards().insert(Vvalues[place]->getSize()-1, *card);

I understand that the types of the elements I'm sending to insert don't match insert's signature, but I can't figure out why.

this is my function:

```
bool Hand::addCard(Card* card)
{
int place = Hand::searchCard(card); // the case that there is values in Vvalues but no one of them contain &card value
if (place <0)
{
    Value* v = new Value(card);  
    if (place == -1 || place == -2)    Vvalues.insert(Vvalues.begin(),v);
    else if (place == -3)    Vvalues.insert(Vvalues.end(),v);
    else if (place == -4)    insertValueSortedWay(v); 
}
else
{
Vvalues[place]->getVcards().insert(Vvalues[place]->getSize()-1, *card);
}
return true;
```

}

and than I try to compile and I get this:

```
src/Hand.cpp:71:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Card*>::insert(int, Card&)’
     Vvalues[place]->getVcards().insert(Vvalues[place]->getSize()-1, *card);
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: `Vvalues[place]->getSize()-1` doesn't give you a valid iterator for `Vvalues`. Looks like you rather want `Vvalues.end()` there.

Comment: `insert` takes an iterator, not an index.

Comment: You probably want to use `std::vector::push_back()` and not `insert`.

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the same error

Comment: I also tried push_back but got a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::insert doesn't take int as a parameter.

Your `getSize()`  function is returns an int, and instead takes a iterator.

Here are the valid parameters for vector::insert in c++11

`insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);`

`insert (const_iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);`

`insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`

`insert (const_iterator position, value_type&& val);`

`insert (const_iterator position, initializer_list<value_type> il);`